# Cloudfront: redirect a whole distribution to a newer one

Tags: redirect, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

We have tons of files (images) on a S3 Bucket, which will be served by a cloudfront distribution to the users browser.
Most images in the bucket changed to a better compression algorithm, but the files are still cached for the next 30 days in the cloudfront edge locations.

Over the time, we created some more distributions to deliver newer versions of the existing files in the bucket. From now on we use Invalidation, but there are still existing distributions which are still referenced in search engines and other sites.

Now we would like to redirect every request from the old distributions to the newest one:

```
GET http://old-distribution.amazonaws.com/user/filename.jpg
```

should send 301 redirect permanent to

-> http://**new**-distribution.amazonaws.com/user/filename.jpg

Is this possible? If yes, how to achieve?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it's possible, with a little help from S3.

Create an empty bucket in Amazon S3.  The name isn't critical as long as it is valid -- lowercase alpha, numbers, and dashes only.  We'll say `example-bucket`.

In this new bucket, in bucket properties, under static website hosting, choose "redirect all requests to another domain."  Enter the hostname of the new Cloudfront distribution, with out the `http://`.

Right above that, note the `Endpoint:`, which will be something like `example-bucket.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com`.

Save your changes, then try to hit the new endpoint with your browser.  Any path you enter should be redirected to the same path at your new distribution.

You've just created an origin server that will generate the redirects you want Cloudfront to return.

The final steps for making this live -- which you may want to test using a different origin, created for the purpose -- are these:

In your old distribution, create a new *custom* origin -- **not** an "S3 origin."  Use the endpoint hostname you just tested as the origin hostname.

Be sure you configure it to send all requests to this origin as HTTP, and don't whitelist the `Host` header for forwarding to the origin, since that won't work.

Create a cache behavior matching path pattern `*` that uses this origin, and remove the others.

Your distribution will now send all requests to your new "custom origin," which is actually provided by S3, and will respond with `301 Moved Permanently` and redirect browsers to the same path in the new distribution.

Comment: How can I create a "custom origin"? For me it seems only to be possible to create a "s3 origin".

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  When entering the origin domain name, do not select the bucket from the list -- instead, manually key in the endpoint hostname you learned from the S3 console.

Comment: Thank you very much for clarifying. The last lesson would be to change the default caching behaviour. It's not possible to delete the default entry, and i can't find any option to mark a newly created cache behaviour as "default". Set the asterik in path pattern isn't enough apparently

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `ViewerRequest` or `OriginRequest` event via `Lambda@Edge` to redirect.

`OriginRequest` is better because response is cached.